# PHP idiom for a counter over non-negative ints

Tags: php, integer-overflow

In trying to make a counter that returns to 0 when the int range is exhausted. Essentially, `0, 1, ..., MAX_INT - 1, MAX_INT, 0, 1, ...`

The idiomatic C is

```
x = ((x + 1) & MAX_INT);
```

But this won't work in PHP because the int gets promoted to a double when it overflows. The cleanest I can come up with is `x = x == PHP_INT_MAX ? 0 : x + 1`, but it's messier.

Comment: `$x += ($x == PHP_INT_MAX) ? -PHP_INT_MAX : 1;` perhaps? [Demo](https://3v4l.org/d0oAS)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
$x = ($x + 1) % (PHP_INT_MAX+1);
```

Comment: Coming from C, <double> % <double> scares me, especially when one can't be an int.

Comment: I was actually surprised that this worked with `PHP_INT_MAX+1`, but it does!

Comment: I first tried `% PHP_INT_MAX`, but that caused it to skip over the max int. I was all set to post  a comment saying there's no better way than the way in the question, but then I tried this just to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intval()` to force using integers:

```
$x = intval($x + 1) & PHP_INT_MAX;
```

Try it out: `echo intval(PHP_INT_MAX + 1)`: https://3v4l.org/7jlPN

### Update:

The manual on [Converting to integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) states:

> If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms other than Windows), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!

So you are right, while this is consistent for current implementations, the result is specified to be undefined and you should not rely on it.

That leaves you with more verbose solutions, either with `%` modulus or the ternary conditional as you already have it (which I would prefer for clarity and robustness).

Comment: That seems to work, but the docs for `intval()` aren't clear about what was going on behind the scenes, just that it returns an int.